# In webview getting error like this Trying to embed a platform view but the PaintContext does not support embedding

Tags: ios, flutter, webview, wkwebview

> Added key on my info.plist file
> io.flutter.embedded_views_preview = YES
>
> In webview loading base 64 converted html string. It's working fine in
> android but iOS  i'm getting error on above mentioned

```
String htmlText =getHTML(cp);
    final String contentBase64 = base64Encode(const Utf8Encoder().convert(htmlText));
    String url = 'data:text/html;base64,$contentBase64';
    this.child = WebView(
        initialUrl: url,
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>[
          _cpJavascriptChannel(buildContext,cp),
          ].toSet(),
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _controller.complete(webViewController);
        },
        navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {return NavigationDecision.prevent;}
    );

      JavascriptChannel _cpJavascriptChannel(BuildContext context, chargePoints.ChargePoint cp) {
        return JavascriptChannel(
            name: 'ChargePoint',
            onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
              Navigator.of(buildContext).pushReplacementNamed('/chargePoint',arguments: {'cp':cp,'connector':message.message});
            });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that helped me in fixing this issue.

```
<key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
<true/>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
<true/>
```

You can also read more about new changes from [Flutter Documentations](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin)